# How to show available wifi connections with react-native for IOS

Tags: tcp, react-native, wifi

I'm developing an IOS React Native App that connects with a device via WiFi, and once connected comunicate via TCP, but I can't even get it to show the list of available connections. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Found any solutions?

Comment: @Sanoop Not really, what I did was redirect the user to the wifi settings using Linking